# Book recommendations for GCSE student

Tags: complex-numbers, book-recommendation

I am currently doing GCSEs so I have a pretty basic knowledge on mathematics.
A teacher told me to read a book on complex numbers as it will be useful. I know what complex numbers are but dont really understand it. Does anyone have any recommendations of a book (complex numbers) which starts with the basics???

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/ComplexNumbers.aspx

That page should cover all you need to know. Individual books on complex numbers would go into too much detail.

Comment: This is very specific to GCSE, so it would be better to ask your teachers or look at test materials.

Answer (score 0):

You should watch examsolutions' videos, they have whole sections for GCSE's and A-Levels, he explains everything very well and you do examples with him which will help you understand it better! Here's the playlist for complex numbers: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5pdglZEO3Ni_482ywsWzMb7MxvfvYI1I

I watched his videos ang got an A* in maths and further maths. Hope this helps!